# How to Extract 'sourceUrl' from JSON with '__typename' as 'Clip' and Non-Empty 'name'

Tags: php, json, parsing

I'm trying to extract "sourceUrl" values from a JSON dataset in PHP, but with specific conditions. The JSON structure contains objects with various properties, and I'm interested in extracting "sourceUrl" when the "__typename" field is "Clip," and the "name" field is not empty.

Here's an example of the JSON structure:

[JSON CODE](https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/1154143677919911936)

I need "https://geo.dailymotion.com/player/xb9cu.html?video=k27SyjVwndhtW8yKNBI" url in this json code, but I need to do this in php, I also need to get the "__typename": "Clip" and "name": "" can't be empty or it will get other dailymotion.com urls in the json code

```
<?php
$json_url = 'https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/1154143677919911936';
$json_data = file_get_contents($json_url);

$data = json_decode($json_data, true);

$sourceUrls = [];

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (
        isset($value['sourceUrl']) &&
        isset($value['__typename']) &&
        isset($value['name']) &&
        $value['__typename'] === 'Clip' &&
        $value['name'] !== ''
    ) {
        $sourceUrls[] = $value['sourceUrl'];
    }
}

if (!empty($sourceUrls)) {
    foreach ($sourceUrls as $sourceUrl) {
        echo 'sourceUrl: ' . $sourceUrl . '<br>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'none.';
}
?>
```

This is the code I tried but I got no result

Comment: Have you tried the official php SDK from Daily Motion?

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with dailymotion, I just want to get that sourceUrl from the json I gave with php